# Azure Devops Pull Request Not Finishing 'Checking for merge conflicts'

Tags: azure-devops, merge, pull-request

I am trying to finish a pull request and I noticed that it never finishes checking for merge conflicts (The little 'in progress' wheel just spins forever). Also when I go to complete the pull request and click complete, the merge never happens. Any ideas on what may be happening? I am on a air-gapped network. Does Devops need a connection to the internet to work correctly as far as completing a pull request? I have checked to make sure that all the correct permission are applied and everything seems to be in order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this issue, I had to use the install utility and do a repair. Once I did this, everything runs as expected.

Answer (score 6):

It happened to me too. For me, I click on "restart merge" and it worked. No idea why.

[image]

Comment: I tried this and it still doesn't work. I'm still not sure what is going on. Right now I have to do all my merges manually through git.

Answer (score 1):

We have an on-site devops server. Restarting the server did the trick for us.